# Calling from/until/range twice on a mutable TreeSet results in empty sequence

Tags: scala

While using a mutable scala TreeSet, I came across some weird behavior when invoking range/from/until methods multiple times on the same set.  The following code block distills the issue down:

```
object MapTest extends App{
  override def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val mutableSet = scala.collection.mutable.TreeSet(3, 2, 5)
    println(mutableSet)
    println(mutableSet.from(2).from(3))
    println(mutableSet.until(5).until(3))
    println(mutableSet.range(2, 4).range(2, 4))
    println(mutableSet.from(2).until(4))

    val immutableSet = scala.collection.immutable.TreeSet(3, 2, 5)
    println(immutableSet)
    println(immutableSet.from(2).from(3))
    println(immutableSet.until(5).until(3))
    println(immutableSet.range(2, 4).range(2, 4))
    println(immutableSet.from(2).until(4))
  }
}
```

which produces the following output

```
TreeSet(2, 3, 5)
TreeSet()
TreeSet()
TreeSet()
TreeSet()

TreeSet(2, 3, 5)
TreeSet(3, 5)
TreeSet(2)
TreeSet(2, 3)
TreeSet(2, 3)
```

As you can see, the immutable set behaves as expected, allowing multiple invocations of from, until, and range.  However on a mutable map, any invocation beyond the first results in an empty list.  (I did also verify that a single invocation of from, to, or range on a mutable map did the right thing).

If it matters, I'm using scala 2.10.3

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue but I could not. Everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When trying the code on my computer, I get the following output :

```
TreeSet(2, 3, 5)
TreeSet(3, 5)
TreeSet(2)
TreeSet(2, 3)
TreeSet(2, 3)
TreeSet(2, 3, 5)
TreeSet(3, 5)
TreeSet(2)
TreeSet(2, 3)
TreeSet(2, 3)
```

So I guess it's a bug. I am running it under 2.11.6

Comment: Ah, yup.  I should've tried it under 2.11 before I bothered posting.  I just recreated it on my work box and it fails under 2.10.6 and works under 2.11.7.